# Увеличение изображения на hovere

Tags: jquery, hover, html, эффекты, css

Добрый вечер!

Есть [заготовка](http://jsfiddle.net/waGdZ/13/),
нужно реализовать по такому же принципу такое же увеличение изображения стульев, только еще с кнопкой внизу "Купить".

Затык в том, что здесь hover срабатывает при добавлении/удалении класса `addClass('class')/removeClass('class')`. Мне нужно, чтобы это был блок с картинкой и кнопкой. Вот уже целые сутки ломаю голову, как это правильно сделать, если с помощью append, то как тогда правильно восстанавливать блок в исходную позицию? (remove и empty удаляют не только всплывающий блок, но и саму исходную картинку.) Помогите, плиз, отблагодарю! :)

Answer (score 1):

Пример очень плохой, как по мне, но пусть кнопка изначально будет с `display: none`, а после наведения ей тоже добавлялся бы класс, который отобразил бы её.

Comment: Ну, допустим - добавил я класс, а как его после этого убрать? И еще проблемка в том, что изначальная картинка уменьшенная, а всплывающая - увеличенная.

Comment: Ничего не пойму, что плохого в том, что изначальная картинка уменьшенная, а всплывающая - увеличенная?

Comment: Без javascript и прочей делюги, если я, конечно, правильно понял задачу
http://jsfiddle.net/0tate7Lj/